# Variable scope in dynamic functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm fairly new to Javascript and wrote the following jQuery code which works:

```
function updateItems() {
        var now = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);

        $(".something").each(function() {

             $(this).html(now.toString());

        });
}

updateItems();
```

Why does this work? One might think that `now` would not be accessible from inside the function. I guess I could run some tests to see what happens if I try to modify `now` from inside the function, if I run another `each()` right after that, etc. But a basic understanding of how the scope works here and generally in Javascript cases like this would be greatly appreciated.

Also, is this type of function accurately called a "dynamic function" or is there a better name for it?

Comment: JavaScript scoping is tricky: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope

Comment: Read answers on this question - everything could be clear.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope

Comment: Read closure https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: May be this will help : http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `function() { ... }`, you create what is technically called a **closure**. They effectively can capture everything from the enclosing scope.

If you use `now` in the closure, you would get the value of `now` *when you execute the closure*, and (potentially) not the value it had when you created it.

Note that the *enclosing scope* here is the scope of the *outer function*, not of the *outer block*, and you may have to take extra care if you're creating closures in a loop, for instance.

Comment: Perfect. I was about to write the same when I saw your answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a nested function. It has access to the `now` variable because functions have access to the variables in scope where they're defined (this is actually how globals work as well). It's called a "closure" (it "closes over" the variables in scope where its defined), which sounds obscure, but don't worry — [closures are not complicated](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html) *(disclosure: my blog)* once you know a couple of things about how JavaScript works.

The fun thing here is that it closes over the `now` variable that's specific to that particular call to `updateItems`, and the reference it has is *live* (it's not a *copy* of `now` as of when the function was created). Each call to `updateItems` creates a *new* anonymous function you're passing to `each`, and each of those functions has access to the `now` variable created during the call to `updateItems`. In your case, you're just using it immediately and returning, but what if you kept a reference to the function? What then? The answer is that's fine, it keeps a reference to the `now` variable it relates to:

```
function say(msg) {
    var f = function() {
        alert(msg);
    };
    return f; // We return a reference to the function
}
var s1 = say("Hi");
var s2 = say("there");
s1(); // Alerts "Hi" (see below)
s2(); // Alerts "there"
```

The call to `s1` alerts `"Hi"` because the function created by our call to `say` still has access to the `msg` argument we gave to `say`, even though `say` has returned. And the same for `s2`, of course.

And just to prove that it's not a copy as of when the function is created:

```
function say(msg) {
    // Create the function
    var f = function() {
        alert(msg);
    };

    // Update `msg`
    msg += " (updated)";

    // Return the function
    return f;
}
var s1 = say("Hi");
var s2 = say("there");
s1(); // Alerts "Hi (updated)"
s2(); // Alerts "there (updated)"
```

See how the function used the updated version of `msg`, even though the function was created before we updated it. The function has access to the variable itself, not a *copy* of the variable's value.